# d3 linkHorizontal for straight line curves

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can d3 linkHorizontal be used for straight line curves? If not, am I missing any d3 feature for that kind of link path? Of-course I can always go manual and calculate it myself.

From 
[image: From-this]

To [image: To-this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [d3.curveStep](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveStep), which creates a path with right-angle corners:

```js
 var link = d3.line()
      .x(function(d,i) { return xScale(i); })
      .y(function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
      .curve(d3.curveStep);
    
    var width = 500
    var height = 500
    var margin = 25
    
    var data = [
      [3, 7]
    ]
    
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 1])
     .range([0, width])
    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 10])
     .range([height, 0])
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
      .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
    
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")

    var points = g.selectAll("g")
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
    
    points.append("path")
     .datum(d => d)
     .attr("d", link)
     .style("stroke", "black")
     .style("fill", "none")
    
    points.selectAll("circle")
     .data(d => d)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", (d,i) => xScale(i))
     .attr("cy", (d) => yScale(d))
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("stroke", "none")
     .style("fill", "black")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```