# Using d3 curvestep for a hierarchial structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to build something similar to a hierachial structure using D3 and i am fairly new to this. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867684/d3-linkhorizontal-for-straight-line-curves) is what i am referring to accomplish it.

[image]

I referred the following links to get the links/connectors in this particular fashion

1. Using d3 [curveStep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867684/d3-linkhorizontal-for-straight-line-curves)
2. Using d3 [linkVertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958789/how-to-use-linkradial-to-draw-a-link-between-two-points) (linkRadial)

I keep getting the following error multiple times in developer console:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "function line
```

Probably some error in my link function.

Following code is what i am using

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "black";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        //var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(source.x0, d.y, d)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){
        //return diagonal(d, d.parent) 
        return diagonal(d.x, d.parent.y)
      });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  /*function diagonal(s, d) {

    var path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }*/
  
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    var link = d3.line()
               .x((x) => xScale(x))
               .y((y) => yScale(y))
               .curve(d3.curveStep);

       return link;
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I have commented existing `diagonal` function and tried to introduce `curveStep` of D3. I have also tweaked a few things related to how the inputs are being passed to the `diagonal` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is that d3.line accepts an array of points. You don't end up passing an array to d3.line anywhere.

Your diagonal function should look something like:

```
function diagonal(array) {
     let line = d3.line()
       .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
       .y(function(d) { return d.x; }) // inverted x/y as you have a horizontal tree
       .curve(d3.curveStep);

     return line(array);
}
```

Normally, each link datum is an object, with properties for source and target, we need to pass an array containing both source and target to the diagonal function:

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return diagonal([d.source,d.target])       
})
```

Or an equivalent array.

As you've used nodes themselves as the link data, we can still use the same principle with:

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return diagonal([d,d.parent])
})
```

Or, construct an array with objects that have x/y properties. In your case we'll need to construct some objects to represent points for the line generator as you're storing old positioning data we need to access:

Eg:

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Son of A" },
          { "name": "Daughter of A" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "Level 2: B" }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "black";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        //var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal([{x: d.parent.x0, y: d.parent.y0 },{x: d.parent.x0, y: d.parent.y0 }])
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){
        //return diagonal(d, d.parent) 
        return diagonal([{x:d.parent.x, y: d.parent.y}, d]) // changes here
      });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal([o,o]) // changes here
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // changes to diagonal function:
  function diagonal(array) {

    var link = d3.line()
               .x((d) => d.y)
               .y((d) => d.x)
               .curve(d3.curveStep);

       return link(array);
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! The key was to return an array. That helps!